# Can I use `backend = pyinotify` in fail2ban with centos 7?

Tags: fail2ban

> If using CentOS or Fedora you will need to change the backend option in jail.local from auto to systemd.

I read this from [this post](https://www.linode.com/docs/security/using-fail2ban-for-security/)
But I want to set `backend = pyinotify` in `/etc/fail2ban/jail.local`,is there any problem?

Comment: You probably shouldn't. pyinotify didn't work right much of the time.

Comment: @MichaelHampton,could you give some reference of `pyinotify didn't work right much of the time`?